# How to find values in an array and update the array to keep only these values

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array with values like these:

```
[oranges] => Array
    (
        [cost] => 0.56
        [quantity] => 6
    )

[pears] => Array
    (
        [cost] => 0.34
        [quantity] => 2
    )
```

I want to perform a search, get the search values using $_REQUEST (I've got to use $_REQUEST), then update the original array to display only the values the match the search. How can I do that?

PS: I need to be able to search the array based on item (oranges, pears, etc) and/or price and/or qty.

With my search form, the $_REQUEST is a variable with the in the following format:

```
Array
(
[item] => apple
[qty] => 2
[price] => 
)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you have tried?. What output you want? What output is coming?

Answer (score 3):

hello you might want to handle this a bit better but something like this will do it:

```
$array[$_REQUEST['item']] = array(
                              "cost" => $_REQUEST['price'], 
                              "quantity" => $_REQUEST['qty']
                            );
```

Where $array equals the array you want to change.

Again I would lay this out a bit better and add some validation. (also avoid using request its a big security issue)

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I follow though: would this method update the array? Also, when I tested it, there was no output and it gave me an error if I didn't add "cost" and "quantity" in the search. Ideally I should be able to search by "item" and/or "cost" and/or "quantity" but if I use only one of those it should also work.

Comment: that's fine if you search by the key so "item", will be required. Then run different updates depending on what's set using "isset"